# Processing SAML 2.0 response with Apache CXF RACS

Tags: cxf, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, cxfrs

I am trying to implement a SAML Request Assertion Consumer Service (RACS) with Apache CXF 2.7.7

Unfortunately the response of my Identity Provider does not include a keyInfo (which is defined optional in the SAML specification).

This leads to an exception when processing the response, because CXF tries to load a DOM for the keyInfo.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.ws.security.saml.ext.AssertionWrapper.verifySignature(AssertionWrapper.java:536)
```

I have a valid keystore.properties file as well as the certificate on my RACS site, but this does not chage the behaviour. Is this a bug in CXF or did I miss something to set up for my RACS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussing this problem in the CXF Mailing List, we found out, that it is a bug in CXF Framework. A new issue was created [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5424)

Sending the KeyInfo in a SAML Request is optional (see Specification [Section 5.4.5](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf)).

Currently there is no easy workaround available.